# Split text file to specific delimiter %

Tags: batch-file, text, split

I have a .txt file that has some text lines like this,

```
%_N_LIBER_BROSA_DR_MPF

;$PATH=/_N_WKS_DIR/_N_ACASA_WPD

;PROGRAM LIBER BROSA DREAPTA

;RECHTE SPINDEL LEEREN

CHANDATA(2)

M30%
```

and I need to split it in more files. The delimiter is `%` sign and the new file name must be extracted from the first line `%_N_LIBER_BROSA_DR_MPF` the text between `%_N_` and `_MPF` in this case `LIBER_BROSA_DR`.

Is there anyone that can help me ? Thank you !!

**Edit [Stephan]** (copied from a now deleted "answer"):

The file is an output from a CNC machine that contains cnc programs.

When I am making a new archive of the programs the machine outputs an .txt file with all the programs.

Each program starts with % sign like in the example.

I need to make a script to extract the program from the .txt file and save it into new .txt file with the name from the characters between %*N* and _MPF

```
%_N_000DNC_MPF
;$PATH=/_N_WKS_DIR/_N_000DNC_WPD
; TRANSFER DNC
; !!! A NU SE STERGE !!!
;  PROG:52343001
M30
%_N_DR_LIBER_BROSA_MPF
;$PATH=/_N_WKS_DIR/_N_ACASA_WPD
;PROGRAM LIBER BROSA DREAPTA
;RECHTE SPINDEL LEEREN
CHANDATA(2)
STOPRE
RE_SP2_SOLL_WZG="0"  ;"LAMAJ_20_RAD"  ;"MULTI_CDR_LUNG"    ;"0"
RE_WZW
G04 F5
M30
%_N_STG_LIBER_BROSA_MPF
;$PATH=/_N_WKS_DIR/_N_ACASA_WPD
;PROGRAM LIBER BROSA STG.
;LINKE SPINDEL LEEREN
CHANDATA(1)
LI_SP1_SOLL_WZG="0" ; "DECKEL";"BURGHIU_39";"0"
LI_SP3_SOLL_WZG="DECKEL" ;"MULTI_CDR"
LI_WZW
G04 F2
M30
```

Comment: You should search first and show your code. SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It would also help of you were to provided us with more information on your source text file. What do you mean by `%` is the delimiter? how was the file created? is it output from another script or command process? Are the empty lines intended? Was it supposed to be a single line? _(if not then I'd assume CR/LF would delimit)_.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "eol=€ delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do (
  set "line=%%a"
  if "!line:~0,1!"=="%%" (
    set name=!line:*N_=!
    set name=!name:_MPF=!
  )
  >>"!name!.txt" echo %%a
)
```

Note: choose a character that won't be in the file as `eol` (end of line). Default for `eol` is `;`, so we have to specify another one (because else we would loose the comment lines)